# Convert xml as string

Tags: xml, web-services, xml-serialization, oracle-service-bus

i have a scenario where in i need to send an xml as a tag content in a SOAP request message to a webservice for example

```
<arg_1><xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sometag><somemoretag>abcd</somemoretag></sometag></arg_1></code>
```

arg_1 happens to be an String parameter to a webservice. So i bring in a CDATA section for this

```
<arg_1><![CDATA[<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sometag><somemoretag>abcd</somemoretag></sometag>]]></arg_1>
```

But this keeps throwing me an exception

org.xml.sax.SAXException: WSWS3084E: Error: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize. Message being parsed:

I keep getting this exception. Has anyone seen this before??

Comment: Please show the code you use to create this XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could handle this -

1. Remove the XML Prolog and insert the original XML document into the content of an element in the other document.

```
<arg_1><sometag><somemoretag>abcd</somemoretag></sometag></arg_1>
```

2. Escape the the original XML document like you would any other text content and insert the resulting text into the content of an element.

```
<arg_1>&lt;sometag&gt;&lt;somemoretag&gt;abcd&lt;/somemoretag&gt;&lt;/sometag&gt;</arg_1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue , wherein my xml was not inside the CDATA properly.
For the tags to be treated as String you must use as the below:

```
 <![CDATA[ ---your xml---- ]]>
```

However you have not used the ? before the xml version. The tag should be
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`
In your case its `<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`.